# Accessing PyroCMS Module inside Custom Theme

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have designed a custom theme and I need to be able to load a module I have made into my default.html page. I have written the following so far:

```
<div id="outer-content">
    <div id="content">
        {{ template:body }}
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I replace `{{ template:body }}` with in order to display a custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
In your theme, save your default.html file with the same name as your module. For example, you can create a custom layout file for the blog and save it as blog.html. When the module gets called it uses the layout file with the same name as your module.

If thats not an answer for you try posting on the PyroCMS Modules forum.